# Encontrar a soma dos elementos de uma matriz

Tags: python

Eu estava tentando criar um código que criava uma matriz quadrada de lado *n* e depois somava cada um dos lados para descobrir qual o que tem a soma diferente,
na parte da soma fiquei meio trancado.

Tentei fazer esse código mas não deu certo. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
n = input()
y = []
while len(y) <= (n**2)-n:
    x = map(int,raw_input().split())
    for i in range(n):
        y.append(x[i])

matriz=[]
matriz1=[]
for i in range(n):
    arroz=[]
    for k in range(n):
        arroz.append (y[0])
        del (y[0])
    matriz.append(arroz)
matriz1.append(matriz[0])   

diferente=[]
```

Até este trecho deu certo, ai eu tentei fazer código encontrar o diferente e ir apagando os iguais

```
while True:

    if sum(matriz[0]) = sum(matriz[(len(matriz))-1]) and sum(matriz[(len(matriz))-2]) = sum(matriz[0]):
        del (matriz[0])
        del (matriz[len(matriz)-1]
        del (matriz[len(matriz)-2]
    elif sum(matriz[0]) != sum(matriz[len(matriz)-1]) and sum(matriz[0]) = sum(matriz[len(matriz)-2]):
           diferente.append(matriz[len(matriz)-1])
           del (matriz[0])
        del (matriz[len(matriz)-1]
        del (matriz[len(matriz)-2]
            break
    elif sum(matriz[0]) = sum(matriz[len(matriz)-1]) and sum(matriz[0]) != sum(matriz[len(matriz)-2]):
        diferente.append(matriz[len(matriz)-2])
        del (matriz[0])
        del (matriz[len(matriz)-1]
        del (matriz[len(matriz)-2]
            break
    elif sum(matriz[0]) != sum(matriz[len(matriz)-1]) and sum(matriz[len(matriz)-1]) = sum(matriz[len(matriz)-2]):
        diferente.append(matriz[0])
        del (matriz[0])
        del (matriz[len(matriz)-1]
        del (matriz[len(matriz)-2]
            break

print diferente
```

Comment: Modificar a entrada enquanto tenta extrair uma informação dela geralmente não é boa ideia.

Answer (score 1):

Para somar os lados e identificar qual o menor, pode-se tentar algo do tipo:

```
superior = 0
direita = 0
esquerda = 0
inferior = 0

    for i in range(n):
        superior += [0][i]
        direita  += [i][n]
        esquerda += [i][0]
        inferior += [n][i]
```

Onde `n` é o tamanho da sua matriz. Depois basta compará-los.